# Build sitemap.xml by Java Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, sitemap

I'm building a sitemap.xml by Spring MVC

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset")
public class XmlUrlSet{
@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "url", type = XmlUrl.class))
private List<XmlUrl> sitemap = new ArrayList<XmlUrl>();

public void addUrl(XmlUrl xmlUrl) {
    sitemap.add(xmlUrl);
}

public List<XmlUrl> getXmlUrls() {
    return sitemap;
}
}
```

And it renders like this:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        ...
    </url>
    <url>
        ...
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I just want to know how to add namespace for xml and xml version like Google's sitemap example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc> 
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402575/how-to-generate-the-correct-sitemap-namespace-using-jaxb-and-spring-responsebod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you might have found your solution. Still, this answer may be helpful to someone.

Replacing `@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset")` with `@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset", namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")` would solve your problem.

**Update**

If you have tried above solution. You will get the result something like following.

```
<ns2:urlset xmlns:ns2="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
    </url>
</ns2:urlset>
```

Solve this problem by adding package-info.java file in your package where you have placed XmlUrlSet class with the following content.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.something.com/something", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

It should solve your problem.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: adding package-info.java can't remove the namespace ns2. Do you know why?

Comment: http://w3cgeek.com/jaxb-generated-xml-remove-the-default-root-element-namespace-prefix.html This link saved me. :)

Comment: @YeWin: the link is invalid

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to change the Url in XMLSchema from ```http://www.something.com/something``` to ```http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9```